VueJs OnMount props generate "Expected Object, got Undefined " warning
I've got the following component:
<template>
  <Grid :items="items" />
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import Grid from '@/components/Grid.vue'
  import { getData } from '@/services/getData'

  const items = ref()

  onMounted(async () => {
    items.value = await getData()
 })
</script>

The Grid component instance needs items to be populated in order to display data, but I need to run getData() to have the data ready. When I run this code I get a type check failed for prop "items". Expected Object, got Undefined warning.
It happens because when the file is first initiated items doesn't have anything until getData() is finished. How can I have getData() run before the warning can show up?

Why don't you just call getData in the <script> block directly?

@TimRoberts I'm calling it this way so that ‘items‘ gets the returned value of ‘getData()‘

You could set a v-if on the Grid component until items are populated. Or allow it to either have an Object or nothing. At the end of the day, it is just a warning and if your grid is properly reactive afterward, it's not a big deal (if it's not, use some nextTick to update the Grid component).

perhaps const items = ref({})

Initializing with empty object is rarely a good idea. There are no nested properties and no straightforward way to distinguish it from initialized one in case it's possible for getData to return empty object too

If Grid relies on a value, it shouldn't be rendered until a value is initialized.
It's either:
<Grid v-if="items" :items="items" />

Or:
const items = ref()
items.value = await getData()

The latter options makes the component async and requires to use <Suspense> in parent components.

Before the data is loaded your items.value is undefined so causing the error.
Initialize it to
const items = ref(<object>)

where <object> is your appropriate format to feed the grid initially (either an object (with particular format or empty) or an array).
